Will a hot piece of metal in water give off energy to its surrounding?
If a piece of hot metal (around 100 degrees celsius) is placed in a cup of water (around 32 degrees celsius) the metal will naturally give off heat to the water, until they reach a final temperature. However, will the metal also give off heat to the surrounding air? The air is around 20 degrees celsius.

It could, but unlikely due to the relatively low temperature of the metal, via infra-red but it all depends on how much the radiation is attenuated by the water.

And how do you distinguish between the metal giving off the energy, or the (warmer) water giving off the energy, including energy the water has received from the metal?

There are three methods of heat transfer: conduction, convection, and radiation. Conduction and convection rely on contact, so the metal is not in contact with the water. Thus there will be no conduction or convection between the metal and the air. So the only remaining possibility is radiation.
For radiative heat transfer to occur between the metal and the air the radiation must first pass through the water. This is possible because water is transparent. However, water is mainly transparent in the visible range of the spectrum, and the bulk of the thermal radiation at these temperatures will be in the infrared range where water is not necessarily transparent. However, in any region where water is transparent the thermal radiation will pass through the water and into the air.
Just because the radiation escapes the water doesn’t mean that it will get absorbed by the air. The air is also transparent to visible light. At infrared frequencies air can absorb some energy, the basis of the greenhouse effect. However, it overall air is more transparent than water. So there are very few wavelengths that will be transparent to water and absorbed by air.
So, the bottom line is that while radiative heat transfer between the water and the air can occur, it will be very small. You could estimate it by comparing the infrared absorption spectra of water and air to find wavelengths where water is transparent and air absorbs. Then look at the black body spectrum for 100 C and integrate over that range.
